# The order in which to build, or, proof a German sentence (I'm around A2 level)

Tags: sentence-structure

Let's assume I know all the words I want to use in a sentence (a big assumption, but let's move on).  For sake of example, let's use a simple sentence, in English, like this:  *The dog takes the bone into a red house.*

I a perfect world, I'd like the list of all the things I have to do to that sentence and the order I should do them in and then I'd just iterate through until there are no problems.  For example (just an example of what I'm trying to do, not that I think that I'm right):

1. Write the subject - *Der Hund*
2. Write the object - *Der Knochen*
3. Write the verb - *nehmen*
4. Write the object of the prepositional phrase - *das Haus*
5. Fight back the voices telling me I'm stupid and that I'll NEVER get this
6. Figure out if the adjective needs to be strengthened - *das rote Haus* becomes - *ein rotes Haus*
7. Start building left-to-right

   ---

   - *Der Hund* …
8. Conjugate the verb - *Der Hund nimmt* …
9. Pick the right article for the object based on case - *Der Hund nimmt den Knochen* …
10. Start the beginning of the prepositional phrase - *Der Hund nimmt den Knochen in* …
11. Pick the right article for the object of the prepositional phrase based on the preposition - *Der Hund nimmt den Knochen in einem* …
12. Now change my mind about the strengthening of the adjective since the article just became strong, but doubt myself and go back to fighting back the voices. - *Der Hund nimmt den Knochen in einem roten* …
13. Take it home. - *Der Hund nimmt den Knochen in einem roten Haus.*

Hmm... Looking back, maybe I should add 5a. Do the preposition and the following article together so I can avoid step 12.… *in einem*

Anyway, you get the idea of what I'm trying to do.  Maybe you've got a link to a perfect page that's already done this and more for really tricky sentences (let's not forget tecamolo)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but seeing *into* is a good indicator that you probably want an accusative object in German.

Comment: Also, a better translation of verbs is often found if its companions are considered, e.g. _to take X_ → _X nehmen_, but _to take X into Y_ → _X in Y bringen_.

Comment: Well, what is your question?

Comment: There is no working algorithm to translate natural languages between each other. If there was, I wouldn't have to write in English here for you to be able to read in English. Also: Translation between languages is only useful, if you have a text from person A that you need to translate for person B. If you're writing a text in some different language, write it in that language in the first place. Like me right now: I'm not thinking/writing German here and than translating, I'm just thinking and writing in English from the start (possibly with some German influence, but still not translating).

Comment: Let's in fact forget tecamolo... it clouds what's really happening and is NOT part of German as a rule.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. How to make a proper sentence? Make everything how it's supposed to be. How to proof one? Check if everything is how it's supposed to be. The order doesn't matter. You can check word order first and then look at articles or the other way around.Also, German has flexible, context dependent sentence structure so any scheme smaller than a full page is bound to fail you.

Comment: Mein Gott!!  You guys are amazing!  This is JUST what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @Emanuel: I think the question was: "What things do I have to pay attention to when building a German sentence, and (in brief), what are the necessary rules for that?" The order in which to do that is not really important (and indeed opinion-based). I think it's a valid question, and the answer(s) can be helpful, because many non-native speakers struggle with that as it's often not taught properly. The comment by JimNellis seems to indicate the question was properly answered. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'll do a top-down approach, instead of "first this, then that, then ...".

1. Choose the correct verb pattern (verb + objects/prepositions). In this case, "etwas (Akk) irgendwohin bringen" (Pons: ["22. bringen (bewegen)"](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=bringen&l=deen&in=&lf=de)).
2. For adverbials, choose the correct preposition. This depends heavily on the "mental image" connected with the preposition, and you can't guess it from the usage of prepositions in other languages (e.g., English "into"). Here, it's "in". Prepositions take different cases, consult a [list](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=14). For *Wechselpräpositionen* like "in", you must choose between accusative (direction) and dative (location).
3. Decline all objects, lookup gender, lookup the endings.

   - "der Hund" (subject -> nominative; male)
   - "den Knochen" (direct objekt -> accusative; male)
   - "in ein rotes Haus" ("in" + accusative; neuter; indefinite article -> [mixed inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Mixed_Inflection_2) of the adjective )
4. Conjugate the verb: "(der Hund) bringt"
5. Place the verb(s). Here, it's just a main clause, so the conjugated verb is in second position, and there are no other verbs (which would go at the end): "[1] bringt [2] [3] ...". In subclauses, the conjugated verb is at the end, not in second position. In questions, the conjugated verb is in first position (but after the interrogative pronoun, if present).
6. Choose some word order for the objects etc. In principle, word order is free; but there's a natural word order with somewhat complex rules. If you deviate from the natural word order, parts of the sentence get emphasized, sometimes unnaturally so. (If you place the verb(s) in the wrong position, the sentence is wrong). Some basic rules are "nominative before dative before accusative", "time before manner before place" (attention, in English, it's "place before time), and "known before unkown".

Result: "**Der Hund bringt den Knochen in ein rotes Haus**". Also possible:

- "Den Knochen bringt der Hund in ein rotes Haus." (emphasizes "den Knochen": It's the bone that the dog takes ...)
- "In ein rotes Haus bringt der Hund den Knochen." (emphasizes "Haus")
- "In ein rotes Haus bringt den Knochen der Hund." (emphasizes "Haus" and "Hund", the latter very strongly)

Answer (score 2):

In the following I assume that...

- ... you know *what* you want to say. For example that you know the English sentence *The dog takes the bone into a red house* that you want to translate.
- ... you know all the words.
- ... you only want to focus on grammar, i.e. morphology and syntax.

Let's start with your sentence:

1. **Identify the parts of the sentence.**

   1. **Identify the subject.**
      Here the subject is *the dog* which translates to *der Hund*. Since in German subjects require the nominative case, *der Hund* is the correct form.
   2. **Identify the verb.**
      Here it is *to take sth.*; in this example this would translate to German *etwas (Akk.) bringen*. The case (accusative) is dictated by the verb; you need not put much thought into it because which verb needs which object cases is more like something that has to be learned by heart.
   3. **Conjugate the verb properly.**
      The subject of the sentence is a singular noun so the verb must be in third person, singular. Tense is present, mood is indicative, voice is active. After conjugating the verb correctly (e.g. by looking it up in your verb charts), you get *bringt*.
   4. **Identify the objects.**

      1. **Identify the accusative object.**
         In 1.2 you found that the verb *bringen* requires an accusative object. The thing that is brought is *the bone* which translates to *der Knochen*, the accusative is *den Knochen*.
      2. **Identify the prepositional object.**
         You want to describe where the bone is brought to. In the original sentence you have *into a red house*.

         1. **Identify the preposition.**
            *Into* refers to a direction, the proper German equivalent is *in* with the accusative case. (*In* with the dative case would refer to location rather than a direction.)
         2. **Identify the object.**
            *A house* translates to *ein Haus*. As you can see in 1.4.2.1, the proper preposition *in* requires the accusative case. The accusative of *ein Haus* happens to be *ein Haus*.
         3. **Choose the correct form of the adjective.**
            You want to translate the adjective *red*, which becomes *rot*. Now you have to determine the correct suffix. *Ein Haus* uses the indefinite article which requires mixed declension of the adjective; *ein Haus* is - according to 1.4.2.2 - in accusative, and it is a neuter noun. So you take your table for adjective declension and look for mixed declension, neuter, accusative and you'll find *rotes*.
         4. **Put the prepositional object together.**
            You arrive at *in ein rotes Haus*.
2. **Make a matrix for your sentence**.
   You have four slots to fill: The subject *der Hund* takes a slot, the verb *bringt* takes a slot, the accusative object *den Knochen* takes a slot and the prepositional object *in ein rotes Haus* takes a slot. So your matrix has four slots:
   _____ _____ _____ _____.
3. **Fill the matrix.**

   1. **Fill in the verb.**
      Your example sentence is a regular main clause, so the verb comes in second position (this is called *Verbzweitstellung* or *V2-Stellung*):
      _____ bringt _____ _____.
   2. **Fill in the other slots.**
      Technically, you could randomly fill in the other three slots. Every sentence would be a correct German sentence:

      - (Der Hund) (bringt) (den Knochen) (in ein rotes Haus).
      - (Der Hund) (bringt) (in ein rotes Haus) (den Knochen).
      - (Den Knochen) (bringt) (der Hund) (in ein rotes Haus).
      - (In ein rotes Haus) (bringt) (der Hund) (den Knochen).
      - ...
        However, in each sentence the focus and emphasis of the parts vary. In a neutral sentence you would put the subject in the first slot, the accusative object *den Knochen* in third position and the prepositional object in last position, so that you'd arrive at *Der Hund bringt den Knochen in ein rotes Haus.*

If I compare your method with mine, the main difference is in your point 7 which is *Start building left-to-right*. My advise would be to think in slots and start to tuck the verb in its slot and model everything else around it. (Some grammar theories use the term *Feld*, e.g. [in the Wikipedia article *Feldermodell des deutschen Satzes*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldermodell_des_deutschen_Satzes) but *Felder* are not quite the same as my slots.)